# IPython fails to load a module where the standard interpreter works

Tags: python, ipython

I can't load a python module in IPython that works fine in the normal interpreter. I have analyzed the problem and somehow IPython does not find a module, whereas the standard console does:

This works in the normal interpreter:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append(r'c:\development\...\ns.package-10.1.0.3-py2.7.egg')
>>> from ns import package
>>>
```

But on IPython it does not:

```
In [2]: import sys

In [3]: sys.path.append(r'c:\development\...\ns.package-10.1.0.3-py2.7.egg')

In [4]: from ns import package
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c019e2988e33> in <module>()
----> 1 from ns import package

ImportError: cannot import name package
```

I find this pretty confusing. I am new to IPython and I don't know where to start. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The key thing you have to recall here is that usually there's not just one `python` interpreter on your machine. Many systems nowadays come with both `python2.7` and `python3.x`, maybe there are more. Every interpreter maintains its own set of installed packages and has its own set of installed scripts, such as `ipython` or `pip`.
When you type `pip` in your shell it's often not obvious which `pip` you are actually calling. Is it `python3`'s or `python2`'s pip?

And here is where you can get into trouble:

The `ipython` und `python` executables in your PATH do not necessary belong to the same interpreter: Imagine that `python` and `pip` belong to a `python2` installation but you then decide to install `ipython` into your `python3` interpreter.
Now `ipython` sees the the packages of your `python3` interpreter whereas `python` sees all your `python2` packages.

If you compare the output of `which ipython` and `which python` in this case, you will notice that you get paths that belong to different interpreters.

So how can you call the script for your favorite interpreter? If `python` points to your favorite interpreter some packages give you a nice way of calling via `-m` parameter: Instead of `pip install ipython` you can write `python -m pip install ipython` and be sure that you called the `pip` version of your favorite python interpreter.

Similar you can start `ipython notebook` via `python -m IPython notebook`.

Comment: I think this does not explain why ipython does not find a package even when I adjust the sys.path manually

Comment: @ikaros45, oh I didn't pay much attention there, sorry. I cannot reproduce this here on linux though. Can you add the output of `import ns; print ns` to your question? Does `python` actually load the file from the path you add to `sys.path`?

Comment: @ikaros45 It still could explain the difference because your IPython might have an `ns` package in `sys.path` _before_ your addition of the egg but without something named `package` in it!

Comment: @BlackJack technically that is right. But in the real code I did a ``sys.path.insert(0,...)`` to make sure it is reached before anything else...

Answer (score 0):

All the above is true, thanks @cel. I break my installs every month or so b/c I'm an admin installing and removing and such. I broke my stuff last week and had the same problem as above, except for python3 specifically. All I did was `pip3 uninstall ipython; pip3 install ipython` and I got my pandas and other libraries linked back usable.

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install ipython
```

If you come to the terminal and write this code, the problem will be solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).